# Failing to obtain correct accrued interest with QuantLib Inflation Bond pricer in Python

Tags: python, precision, quantlib

I am trying to price an inflation bond using QuantLib-Python. I seem to be producing numbers very close to Reuters and Bloomberg when I compare my data, however, I can not get the accrued interest to match.

Both Reuters and Bloomberg are showing 0.062230211, however, my code is producing 0.062285744677396664. I have tried modifying my daycount assumptions, settlement day assumptions and a few other things to no avail.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

calendar = ql.UnitedKingdom()
lag = 3

today = ql.Date(23, 8, 2019)
evaluationDate = calendar.advance(today, 1, ql.Days)
dayCounter = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)
convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
lag = 3

# ISIN: GB00BDX8CX86
# inflation fixing lag period (3mths for gilts)
issue_date = ql.Date(25, 9, 2013)
maturity_date = ql.Date(22, 3, 2068)
fixing_date = calendar.advance(evaluationDate,-lag, ql.Months)

observationLag = ql.Period(lag, ql.Months)

# assign evaluation date
ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(evaluationDate)

# derives a quantlib yield term structure for discounting
yTS = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(evaluationDate, 0.01033692, dayCounter))

# define period gap
tenor = ql.Period(1, ql.Months)

# define RPI schedule within Quantlib
from_date = ql.Date(31, ql.August, 2018);
to_date   = ql.Date(31, ql.July, 2019);
convention = ql.Unadjusted
rpiSchedule = ql.Schedule(from_date, to_date, tenor, calendar, 
                               convention, convention,
                               ql.DateGeneration.Backward, True)

# manually input RPI fixings for now
fixData = [284.2, 284.1, 284.5, 284.6, 285.6,
            283, 285, 285.1, 288.2, 289.2, 289.6, 289.5]

dte_fixings=[dtes for dtes in rpiSchedule]

# this is the going to be holder of the zero swap inflation curve.
cpiTS = ql.RelinkableZeroInflationTermStructureHandle()
inflationIndex = ql.UKRPI(False, cpiTS)

#current interpolated RPI rate
fixing_rate = 289.53548

inflationIndex.addFixing(fixing_date, fixing_rate)

zciisData = [(ql.Date(31,7,2020), 3.1500000000137085),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2021), 3.547500000013759),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2022), 3.675000000013573),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2023), 3.7250000000134342),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2024), 3.750000000013265),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2025), 3.7430000000129526),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2026), 3.741200000012679),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2027), 3.7337000000123632),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2028), 3.725000000011902),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2029), 3.720000000011603),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2030), 3.712517289063011),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2031), 3.7013000000108764),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2032), 3.686986039205209),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2033), 3.671102614032895),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2034), 3.655000000009778),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2035), 3.6394715951305834),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2036), 3.624362044800966),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2037), 3.6093619727979087),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2038), 3.59421438364369),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2039), 3.5787000000081948),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2040), 3.5626192748395624),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2041), 3.545765016376823),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2042), 3.527943521613608),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2043), 3.508977137925462),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2044), 3.48870000000685),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2045), 3.467083068721011),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2046), 3.4445738220594935),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2047), 3.4216470902302065),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2048), 3.3986861494999188),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2049), 3.376000000005752),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2050), 3.3538412080641233),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2051), 3.3324275806807746),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2052), 3.311938788306623),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2053), 3.2925208131865835),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2054), 3.274293040759302),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2055), 3.2573541974782794),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2056), 3.241787355503245),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2057), 3.227664186159851),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2058), 3.2150486140060774),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2059), 3.204000000004159),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2060), 3.1945334946674064),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2061), 3.1865047145143377),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2062), 3.179753073456304),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2063), 3.1741427790361154),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2064), 3.1695593261025223),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2065), 3.1659065919088736),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2066), 3.163104428386987),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2067), 3.1610866681252903),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2068), 3.1597994770515836),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2069), 3.159200000003204),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2070), 3.159242349440139),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2071), 3.1598400898057433),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2072), 3.16090721831932),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2073), 3.162369676612098),
 (ql.Date(31,7,2074), 3.1641636543027207)]

# bootstrap the inflation swap curve (quantlib)
zeroSwapHelpers = [ql.ZeroCouponInflationSwapHelper(rate / 100,observationLag,
    date, calendar, convention, dayCounter, inflationIndex) for date,rate in zciisData]

# the derived inflation curve
jj=ql.PiecewiseZeroInflation(evaluationDate, calendar, dayCounter, observationLag,\
                             inflationIndex.frequency(), inflationIndex.interpolated(),\
                             zciisData[0][1],#baseZeroRate,\
                             yTS, zeroSwapHelpers, 1.0e-12, ql.Linear())

cpiTS.linkTo(jj)

notional = 1000000

# real coupon of bond
fixedRates = [0.125 / 100]    

# bond settings
fixedDayCounter = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)
fixedPaymentConvention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
fixedPaymentCalendar = ql.UnitedKingdom()
contractObservationLag = ql.Period(3, ql.Months)

# how do you observe the index? as-is, AsIndex, Flat, Linear? 
observationInterpolation = ql.CPI.Flat
settlementDays = 1
# Boolean switch 
# - only price elements of bond that appreciate in value due to inflation
growthOnly = False

# base CPI fixing (generated on bond issue date)
baseCPI = 249.7

# generate quantlib schedule
fixedSchedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date,
                  maturity_date, 
                  ql.Period(ql.Semiannual),
                  fixedPaymentCalendar,
                  ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                  ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                  ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
                  False)

# create bond within quantlib library
bond = ql.CPIBond(settlementDays,
                    notional,
                    growthOnly,
                    baseCPI,
                    contractObservationLag,
                    inflationIndex,
                    observationInterpolation,
                    fixedSchedule,
                    fixedRates,
                    fixedDayCounter, 
                    fixedPaymentConvention)

# assign bond pricing engine and set pricing within quantlib
bondEngine=ql.DiscountingBondEngine(yTS)
bond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

# calc bond yield
print(bond.NPV()) 
print(bond.cleanPrice())
compounding = ql.Compounded
yield_rate = bond.bondYield(fixedDayCounter,compounding,ql.Semiannual)
y_curve = ql.InterestRate(yield_rate,fixedDayCounter,compounding,ql.Semiannual)
print(y_curve)

##Collate results
print("Clean Price:", bond.cleanPrice())
print("Dirty Price:", bond.dirtyPrice())
print("Notional:", bond.notional())
print("Yield:", yield_rate)
print("Accrual Period", ql.BondFunctions.accrualPeriod(bond, ql.Date(27,8,2019)))
print("Accrued Period", ql.BondFunctions.accruedPeriod(bond, ql.Date(27,8,2019)))
print("Accrued Days", ql.BondFunctions.accruedDays(bond, ql.Date(27,8,2019)))
print("Accrued Amount:", bond.accruedAmount())
print("Settlement Value:", bond.settlementValue())
```

Expecting accrued interest : 0.062230211
Actual accrued interest: 0.062285744677396664

Comment: hi rngone, did you manage to get the issue fixed?